# implementing retry with backoff in Portable class library

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, portable-class-library, windows-8.1-universal

I am developing a `protable class library(PCL)`. the goal of this `PCL` is registering a push notification channel and also initiating a `MQTT` connection with server. the problem is that the `PCL` must be able to detect transient connection fault and retry with backoff. I find a library called `Polly` for this purpose. `PCL` has a static method (`Init`) that my `Windows Universal 8.1 app` called it from `OnLaunched` method. I want to the PCL doesn't block the `UI Thread`.I can't use `ConfigureAwait(false)` in `OnLaunched` method because only `UI Thread` can access elements that related to `UI`. I think Current `Polly` async implementation blocks `UI Thread`

what is correct way for implementing my PCL library with this assumption? is there a library for retry Purose in `PCL` except `Polly`?

### App.xaml.xs

```
    protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
    {
        // some code

        await Notifier.Init(some parameters);

        // if I use ConfigureAwait(false) I see exceptions in rest of method
        // some code
    }
```

### PCL.cs

```
public sealed class Notifier
{

    public static async Task<bool> Init(some parameters)
    {

        Policy policy = Policy.Handle<NullReferenceException>().WaitAndRetryAsync(5,
                               retryAttempt => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(Math.Pow(2, retryAttempt)), (exception,timeSpan) =>
                               {
                                   Debug.WriteLine(exception);
                                   Debug.WriteLine(timeSpan);
                               });

        policy.ExecuteAsync(() => instance.OpenChannelAndUploadAsync(instance.ServerUrl));

        await instance.InitiateMqtt();


        return true;
    }
```